# tkinter messagebox link to notebook page

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
referwork = ttk.Notebook(root, style =".TNotebook")
f1 = ttk.Frame(referwork)
f2 = ttk.Frame(referwork)
referwork.add(f1, text="Search", padding = 1)
referwork.add(f2, text="Add/Delete", padding = 1)

#referwork.configure (height = 500, width = 800)
referwork.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N,W,S,E))
```

I have used the above to create a two-tab notebook. On the first a search is performed. What I want to do is to have an alert in a message box appear messagebox.askyesno and when 'yes' is selected that the focus moves to the second page of the notebook

```
messagebox.askyesno(0.0,'"{0}"{1} \n {2}\n'.format(search_analyte.get(),' is  not in the database.','Add,if appropriate'))
        if True:
```

is as far as I have got. I cannot figure out how to 'open' the second page using this dialogue and conditional. Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Notebook.select(tab)`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.select) method, where `tab` is one of the notebook child widgets.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno

def open_first():
    referwork.select(f1)
def open_second():
    if askyesno('Title', 'Press "Yes" to open second page') == YES:
        referwork.select(f2)

root = Tk()
referwork = Notebook(root, style =".TNotebook")
f1 = Frame(referwork)
f2 = Frame(referwork)
Button(f1, text='Go =>', command=open_second).pack(padx=100, pady=100)
Button(f2, text='<= Go', command=open_first).pack(padx=100, pady=100)
referwork.add(f1, text="Search", padding = 1)
referwork.add(f2, text="Add/Delete", padding = 1)
referwork.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N,W,S,E))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. Used if True: open_second()